# Firing an Event in Laravel 5

Tags: events, laravel, laravel-5

In an attempt to learn using events I have followed [this tutorial](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-events-and-handlers)

In my App\Events\ThingWasDone.php i have this

```
    Session::put('testevent', 'it works!');


    $author= Entity::find(261);
    $author->still_active_URL = 99;
    $author->save;
```

The Session is properly defined and I can get it in my View files. 
Any attempt to write to DB produces this error:

```
LogicException in Model.php line 2632:
Relationship method must return an object of type
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

I tried options like passin or not passing any variable:

```
\Event::fire(new ThingWasDone($object->id));

\Event::fire(new ThingWasDone());
```

Didn't help.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$author->save;
```

to:

```
$author->save();
```

This might solve the error.

Comment: Does it helpful to you ?

Comment: That was easy. Congrats!

Comment: Thank you.....Some times a Little missing syntax can harass you most as its so small too find